# Creating dynamically sized square (equal height and width) UI elements in Android

Tags: android, layout, user-interface, height, width

As the title states, I am trying to set the width of a layout element to be equal to the height (which is set to match the parent). I've tried setting the width parameter programatically from the height parameter, but this shows up as -1 rather than the actual height (since it matches the parent). Anyone know how I can create square layout elements whose size is dynamic? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

So what I've been doing for things like this -- and I don't know that it's ideal, but it works quite well -- is use `ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener`. Something like this:

```
View myView = findViewById(R.id.myview);
ViewTreeObserver observer = myView.getViewTreeObserver();
observer.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new SquareLayoutAdjuster());

class SquareLayoutAdjuster 
        implements ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        int dimension = myView.getHeight();
        LayoutParams params = myView.getLayoutParams();
        params.width = dimension;
        myView.setLayoutParams(params);
        observer.removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
    }
}
```

That's just the general idea, I don't know if it compiles as is, but basically in the `onGlobalLayout()` method, your views are guaranteed to be measured. You remove the listener at the end to prevent it from being called multiple times (unless you need that to happen for whatever reason).

Answer (score 0):

the solution of KCOPPOCK works for me, thank you. But i got "java.lang.IllegalStateException: This ViewTreeObserver is not alive, call getViewTreeObserver() again" at runtime. So i use
`findViewById(R.id.serie_main_layout).getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);`

instead

```
observer.removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
```

and all works perfectly.